# Yahoo Pipes - Combine item.content fileds of two RSS feeds based on same item.title

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I am wondering whether this can be achieved by using Yahoo Pipes?

1. fetch two RSS feeds
2. compare item.title fields of both feeds
3. replace item.content with combined content of item.content fields if found similar item.title

Comment: just use the union and unique operators.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I need to merge content of the item.content fields if item.title is similar.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by similar but I'd say this is too complicated for a pipe. Take a look at ScraperWiki.

Comment: I mean if both item.title fileds in rss feeds are completely alike/same. BTW, thanks for pointing out to ScraperWiki!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but will need to involve a subpipe (pipe2 called from pipe1)...

Pipe2- This will takes a string input item title... Will "get Feed2"... filter off items whose title not equal to input item title... return the matching item.

Pipe1 - this will "get Feed1" and loop through all the items passing item title to Pipe2... the result from pipe2, if any, will be in node as loop:anything... add content from there to the content of feed1

Drawback: Theoretically feed2 will be called n number of times where 'n' is number of items in feed1... practically Yahoo pipes use cache so should not be a problem...

Comment: I am scratching my head... I would really appreciate if you could draw sample pipe. I tried all possible variants and could not make it work.

Comment: Just tried again with a fresh head and it works exactly as I wanted! **bold**Thank you so much!

Comment: sorry didn't notice your request on time... feeling good that it helped you